# Intersection of the two data sets

Tags: matlab, date, matching, intersect

I have two time series of share prices, `Price1` and `Price2`. `Tday` is the time series of the dates which match for both prices. Now I am trying to match the prices of each to the newly established `tday` (matching dates time series). I am following instructions of building indexes. I then proceed to match them by creating the new `cl1` set which is basically `price1` matching the indexed dates as shown below. My problem is that on my old Matlab this used to work fine. Now the `cl1` comes out to be a very volatile time series which resembles what it should be but is way to volatile with swings of 20-40% from one data point to the next. I am using Matlab 7.12 R2011a now. Can anybody help me correcting this volatility in `cl1` and `cl2`?

```
[tday, idx1, idx2]=intersect(tday1, tday2);

cl1 = adjcls1(idx1);


cl2 = adjcls2(idx2);
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be just fine. Remember that you need to plot `cl1` against `tday1(idx1)` to make sure the numbering is consistent.

Comment: Rody, thnx. I know it looks as it should. Thats the problem. But the data is of cl1 is trendwise same but way more volitile in the short term. I am wondering if this is a compiler issue or something. In my old matlab all worked fine. Any ideas?

Comment: also what do you mean by plot? do u mean chart?

Comment: You will need to show us some example data and the problem. Otherwise all seems fine, at least to me.

Comment: ok uploaded some data.plsease have a look

Comment: Based on how you are displaying the data, it might be that tday is not ordered the way you think it is. Try sorting tday, and then use the sorted indices to order idx1 and idx2.

Comment: Dustin, thank you so much!  I followed your advice and sorted the index, it was all over the place: worked w/ below code. Thanks again!                          index1=sort(idx1,'descend');
adjcls(idx, 1)=adjcls1(index1);

Comment: I recommend you to post this as the answer @dustincarr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you are displaying the data, it might be that tday is not ordered the way you think it is. Try sorting tday, and then use the sorted indices to order idx1 and idx2.